# Jquery code not loading in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

I need help with my jquery code. The code has been lifted from a post, and tested working by a number of people. It is supposed to be for a slideshow. but why is it showing a list of the pictures instead??? Please help me verify my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js">
$(function () {
    /* SET PARAMETERS */
    var change_img_time = 5000;
    var transition_speed = 100;

    var simple_slideshow = $("#exampleSlider"),
        listItems = simple_slideshow.children('li'),
        listLen = listItems.length,
        i = 0,

        changeList = function () {
            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
            });

        };
    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="exampleSlider">
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you cant use a src attribute and put code between the `<script></script>` tags, you need separate ones for each

Comment: The `<script>` tags for jquery reference and jquery/javascript code should be separate. **[This can help you](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)**.

Comment: thanks.. i altered the code but it still doesn't seem to be functioning as a slideshow

Comment: @Leonne Any error in `console`?

Comment: @Leonne Works perfect. https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/aevekngv/

Comment: wow.. console?? which program is that?? im using notepad++..

Comment: @Leonne Browser's dev tools

Comment: oh yea. thanks Tushar and all u guys. Solved it. apparently my jquery.js was in a different folder

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {

.........
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss `</script>`

And your code must in new script tag like `<script> // your code </script>`